# Autocomplete outputting two fields from DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following code for an autocomplete input where the user can input the `nome` of the employee instead of the `ID`:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE nome LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['nome'];
        }



    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The output now it's like this:

[image]

And I need to output the name with the ID but only send the `nome` information to the DB

**UPDATE**
Here's the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/autocomplete.css" />       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
        //autocomplete
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 1,
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function() {}
        }
    });                
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using a javascript library to takes these results from PHP and place them in the dropdown, or are you writing the js code yourself. Whichever way it is either show us the JS code or tell us which library you are using

Comment: Oh of couse sorry!! I've updated the question!

Comment: Recommend to not use `select *` if you need only two columns use `select columna columnb' instead.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks!

Comment: Now what type of element is has the class `.auto`

Comment: @RiggsFolly nothing, it's just the name of the class

Comment: It must be attached to an HTML tag of some dort

Comment: Just on the Input field of `nome` it has `class='auto'`

Comment: Or else, to simplify, Am I able to leave it that way and create another `input(readonly)` just to show the `ID` ? and when the user select an employee that field automatically updates the `ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can return a label and a value to the autocomplete:

In your PHP:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // add the ID inside () chars
    $return_arr[] =  [
        'label' => $row['nome'],
        'value' => $row['id']
    ]; 
}
```

In your JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // manually update the textbox
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // manually update the textbox and readonly field
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#other-input").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

**OR:** You could try putting the ID in some delimiters and then strip the ID out before sending to the database. Something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){

    // strip out the (ID) before searching in DB
    $nomeOnly = preg_replace('/ \(.*\)/', '', $_GET['term']);

    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE nome LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$nomeOnly.'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            // add the ID inside () chars
            $return_arr[] =  $row['nome'] . ' (' . $row['id'] . ')'; 
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like that before, but the problem is that it writes on the input `Name(ID)` and send it to the DB, so it inputs the name and ID Where it only should be the `name` :/

Comment: That's why you include `$nomeOnly = preg_replace('/ \(.*\)/', '', $_GET['term']);` to strip it back out before it gets to the DB.

Comment: But it keeps giving me the error like the employee does not exist

Comment: When i try to `submit` the employee with that dropdown

Comment: And can you strip the characters out in the script where the form submits using the `preg_replace()` above?

Comment: Or you could add an onsubmit to strip it out in JS before submitting the form: `nomeString.replace(/ \(.*\)/g,"")` or something similar.

Comment: I've update the answer to include a second option which puts the ID into a second form field instead.

Comment: sorry for the long time with no response, I've got a problem and only will be able to test it tomorrow :/ But thank you so much for your help  !!